# Url.Action cleanse (remove id)

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to pass an url to a service and I use the Url helper. Problem is, after accessing the respective action once, the route parameter ID gets in the way.

I need the url to set the href value of some links, and all is ok for first run. But after I click on one of those links, the computed href will contain 2 ID's !

I set the URL for the links on some html templates here:

```
List<WidgetViewModel> viewModel = service.GetRenderTemplates(Url.Action("Details", "Notifications"), userName);
```

And somewhere else in code I set the href for the links like this:

```
template = string.Format(
                template,
                releaseNotif.Version,
                url + "/" + notification.Id.ToString() + "?typeId=" + notification.TypeId.ToString(),
                colorCssClass,
                notificationClass
                );
```

If my URL points to the specified "Details" action, instead of getting a clean URL (without ID) with Url.Action, I get an url containing ID. Instead of this:

```
/xxx.Website/MyController/MyAction
```

I get this:

```
//xxx.Website/MyController/MyAction/SomeID
```

Is there any way to get a "clean" (no ID) Url from Url.Action helper method ?

Answer (score -1):

Found the answer on SO:  I use Url.Content instead of Url.Action